# How to get CR2 (Canon raw) support for XLoadImage?

Tags: arch-linux, x11, images

I've been looking for a light-weight image viewer to replace gThumb now that I'm not running Gnome anymore, and found XLoadImage. How can I add support for Canon's raw CR2 format?

```
anna@anna:~ $ xloadimage IMG_0001.CR2 
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Photometric tag is missing, assuming data is YCbCr.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, SamplesPerPixel tag is missing, applying correct SamplesPerPixel value of 3.
OJPEGSubsamplingCorrect: Warning, Subsampling tag is not set, yet subsampling inside JPEG data [2,1] does not match default values [2,2]; assuming subsampling inside JPEG data is correct.
IMG_0001.CR2 is a 5184x3456 24-bit single-plane YCBCR TIFF image
IMG_0001.CR2: YCBCR  is an unsupported TIFF photometric style, sorry.
IMG_0001.CR2: unknown or unsupported image type
anna@anna:~ $
```

The only thing I've found so far is a plugin for GIMP, but GIMP is definitely not light-weight.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool [dcraw](http://cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/) that will process raw files to jpegs.

There are also several libraries for working with RAW files:

- [LibRaw](http://www.libraw.org)
- [libopenraw](http://libopenraw.freedesktop.org/wiki)

Comment: Do you know of an image viewer that uses any of the libs?